# Full-text search in notmuch (like multi-occur)?

Tags: search, email, occur, notmuch

Has anyone tried to search through emails' contents in [notmuch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Notmuch) in a "multi-occur like fashion", that is in a buffer that lists occurrences of a searched keyword and let's you visit their buffers (email messages)?

From my simple tests it looked like notmuch indexes contents of emails, as well as its headers, so I assume that this should be possible?

If anyone is aware of any other project that has this feature (mu4e, neomutt) please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing it in two discrete steps:

1. open all buffers from the current (tree) search (may take a few seconds):

```
(defun notmuch-tree-show-all-messages ()
        (interactive)
        (goto-char (point-min))
            (while (and (not (eobp)) (not (get-buffer (notmuch-tree-get-message-id))))
              (notmuch-tree-show-message-out)
              (previous-buffer)
              (forward-line 1)))
```

2. multi-occur only in the opened notmuch messages:

```
(defun my-multi-occur-in-notmuch-message-matching-buffers (regexp &optional allbufs)
  "search only in notmuch messages"
  (interactive (occur-read-primary-args))
  (multi-occur-in-matching-buffers "notmuch" regexp (not allbufs)))
```

[ref[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641211/emacs-interactively-search-open-buffers)

May be worth noting that just for the purpose of full-text email search, I'm testing [recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/index-recoll.html) now instead, which indexes all emails ahead of time.